# Linking DLL with .DEF or .LIB file

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker

Caution: I know nothing about C++. I'm comfortable using C#, but this is confusing the hell out of me.

I know this is a common question, but I've spent the last few hours very frustrated - mainly because it's something that should be really simple.

I'm trying to import a DLL into VC++ 2010, and for the life of me I can't figure out the 'nice' way to do it. I have the headers that contain definitions, and a .DEF file that I've converted into a .lib file using the "lib".

All I want to do is to be able to call the functions contained within a DLL! When I try to add it as a reference, I get the following error: Could not add a reference to file WindowsAccessBridge.dll, because it is neither a .NET assembly nor a registered ActiveX control.

I can access the functions with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, but I was really hoping for a 'drop in' solution that wouldn't mean I have to write code for 50+ functions.

TL;DR: How do I import a native C++ dll into my project, in order to call its functions? I have the .lib, .def, and .dll file. Your move?

Edit - I realise the correct answer would be "Learn the language you're trying to write in." - but I'm really hoping there's a simple way to get this done.

Code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "WABAPI.h"
#include "AccessBridgeCalls.h"

WABAPI::WABAPI(void)
{
}

void WABAPI::Init()
{
    initializeAccessBridge();
}
```

Here are my settings in Linker:

[image]

Comment: There's some evidence that you successfully jumped through the hoops to get the DLL #included and linked.  There's no evidence that you are actually trying to call any of its exported functions.  Is wabapi.cpp actually part of your EXE project?  How does execution flow from main() to the Init() function?

Comment: My apologies, I'm creating a new instance of WABAPI from a button_click event, and then calling WABAPI.Init() from there. Just doing that in the meantime for testing purposes - this isn't how it will be used in the end. Also, as for the linking, it's not working. With the settings listed above, I still get the error: error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000008) "extern "C" int __cdecl initializeAccessBridge(void)" (?initializeAccessBridge@@$$J0YAHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall WABAPI::Init(void)" (?Init@WABAPI@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)

Comment: So you made up a .lib file from the .def.  And probably cooked up a .h file.  What does the .def say about the function name?  Does it end with @@$$FQ$AAMXXZ?  You probably didn't declare it properly, extern "C" is common.  Contact the DLL owner to get the files you need to use that DLL.

Comment: I made a lib from a .def file, provided to my by Oracle (DLL owner). They also provide the source code for it, but I'm unable to compile it with the /clr flag, so I thought I would just use the DLL as I have been in C# (Using DLLImport). Hence the situation I find myself in now.

What I'm looking for is a way to just use the functions contained within. I don't really care about the 'right' or 'easy' way anymore - just a way that works would be nice. Thanks for taking the time to respond as far as you have :-)

Comment: @HeWhoWas the error you posted above means that you arn't linking to anything that defines that function. Let us see the .def and .h

Comment: Hey guys, I wasn't adding the correct source files for AccessBridgeCalls. I ended up attempting to compile my own WindowsAccessBridge.dll using the provided source files, and realised it wasn't using that file anywhere. Imported it into my solution, changed some encoding/header settings, and it appears to be working well! Thanks for all your assistance, and sorry to have provided such a noobish problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the header into your source code:

```
#include <your_header.h>
```

Then you tell the linker to use the .lib file:

[image]

This picture is from VS 2008, but if memory serves, the layout in VS 2010 is similar.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I did come to the same logical conlcusion myself, but haven't been able to get it working. It seems to see all my imported functions as being 'non-executable code'. I've updated the original post to include more information if you don't mind having a look at it.

Edit - Keep in mind that the lib file is generated, and I'm not sure on how to confirm that it's working correctly...